# How to find all the expanded or collapsed rows in Kendo UI grid hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

How to find all the expanded or collapsed rows in Kendo UI grid hierarchy?
I can find the count of all the masterrow using below code but I want to interate through each and check which all are expanded.

```
var grid = $("#gridList").data("kendoGrid");
var allMasterRows = grid.tbody.find('>tr.k-master-row')
```

I have tried below code but it does not work

```
var strPlus = (grid.tbody.find("k-icon k-plus"));
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these to find the expanded or collapsed rows:

```
var expandedRows = $('.k-detail-row:visible');
var collapsedRows = $('.k-detail-row:hidden');
```

If you're looking for the icons, your selector is off...it should be:

```
var strPlus = (grid.tbody.find(".k-icon.k-plus"));
```

Comment: No this is not working as its not finding class .k-detail-row

Comment: @Piyush Ah, then your code must be different from the kendo examples. Can you provide a fiddle? Or a sample of the rendered html?

Comment: @Ted...I am trying something like this , though data-bind is not working in the this fiddle [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/@raj_pj/IVoXA/9)

Comment: @Piyush in that linked example, the expanding rows have a class of `k-detail-row`, like in my answer. What we need to know is the class that is on the expanding rows in _your_ code.

Comment: I got it now ,yes I am getting that class too bur somehow "var allMasterRows = grid.tbody.find('>tr.k-master-row');" gives results but var allMasterRows = grid.tbody.find('>tr.k-detail-row');" does not return anything.